# Is there a way to open Visual Studio developer command prompt from a directory?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I just found out that my typing CMD in the search bar a command prompt opens up with that path but I work mostly with developer command prompt, is there a similar way of achiving this?

Comment: In Windows 11, Windows Terminal is built-in and you can type `wt` in the File Explorer's address bar to launch the Terminal in the current directory. In the Terminal setting itself, you can pick the Developer Command Prompt as the default profile for startup.

In case you have Windows 10 instead, while you can install Windows Terminal, it lacks some integration and I don't have any W10 box to test right now, not sure if would work there

Comment: I happen to have windows 11, how would I go about getting into the terminal settings to pick developer command prompt?

Comment: Settings-Startup-Default Profile

Comment: I see, I got it to open the developer prompt but now it doesn't open in the path of the directory I'm in.

Comment: Oh, sorry, turns out right clicking on the empty area of the Explorer and Open Terminal will launch the dev command prompt in that folder, but typing wt directly lost the context

Comment: Thanks! It was getting annoying having to set up my work every time in the longes possible way, the thing is I have this issue where every once in a while the compiler throws a link error because apparently there0s already a file in execution that didn't close properly but the thing is I can't identify it in the task manager so I have to constantly close and open my project every time it happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255484/discussion-between-agutier2-and-martheen).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your Shortcut settings, assuming you're using a shortcut to open this in the start bar. You just need to change the target of the shortcut.

Normally speaking, you can change the "Start in" field, but when opening it as an **Administrator**, the directory specified in that field is overriden to the system32 directory by default due to how Windows handles elevated permissions.

In Properties of the shortcut, prepend the command to change the directory before the call to the command prompt. The `cd /d` command changes the current directory to a specified path and the `/d` switch is used to change the current drive in addition to changing the current directory for a drive.

The Target field should look something like this *(note all of the quotes)*:

```
%COMSPEC% /k "cd /d C:\path\you\want && "C:\path\to\your\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

Where:

- `%COMSPEC%` is the environment variable that points to the command prompt (`cmd.exe`),
- `/k` carries out the command specified by the string and *continues*

Replace:

- `C:\path\you\want` with your desired start directory and
- `C:\path\to\your\VsDevCmd.bat` with the **full** path to the `VsDevCmd.bat` file.

Hope this helps.